# Basic TypeScript NodeJS program with a client-utility-definition structure using strict coding rules

Tags: typescript, module, sample, strict

How should I draw a base TypeScript "barebone" to start a program using strict settings, given the following program structure?

1. A base "client" code with my actual program logic
2. A "utility" module to define functions and extensions (I can then derive other modules from this one)
3. A definition file to allow extensions from the utility module in (2).

All this using strict TypeScript rules to ensure I'm taking advantage of TypeScript features over plain JavaScript. In other words, using a **tsconfig.json** like the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

So, no strict null checks, no plain js allowed, always strict, no implicit any, and each imported type explicitly specified in the project.

The only *"relaxed"* rule here is the `include`, `exclude` and `files` sections from TypeScript project file, so any `.ts`, `.d.ts` and `.tsx` files in the current directory are included in the build process (that is, no unused/unrelated source code in the folder).

Answer (score 0):

After much struggling I could come up with the following structure. Sharing for whoever else may be starting with TypeScript and wanting the same as me.

Having in mind this is a NodeJS application, we will have as the bare minimum, the @types/Node package, installed with `npm -i @types/Node`

## NPM-related tasks

1. Create `package.json` with `npm init`
2. Install `@types/node` with `npm install @types/node`

## TypeScript-related tasks

1. Create the exact same **tsconfig.json** file as the one in the question:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

2. Create sample .d.ts file (this one extending a string with a 'test' function)

**string.d.ts**

```js
interface String {
  test(this: string) : string;
}
```

3. Create the utility module

**utils.ts**

```js
String.prototype.test = function (this : string) : string {
  var str = this;
  str = str + " - test";
  return str;
}

function textIsTest(what : string) : boolean {
  return what == "test";
}

export { textIsTest };
```

4. your "main" code:

**index.ts**

```js
import * as util from "./utils";

let params = process.argv.slice(2); // split commandline arguments

let testString = params[0];

console.log("Commandline parameter: " + testString);
console.log("Extended string: " + testString.test());
console.log("Is 'test': " + util.textIsTest(testString));
```

Did this in hopes this would help other people beginning with TypeScript!..

## Extra: watch + runner

Batch (bash) script to watch-and-run the project. Should work in cygwin, linux and mac (tested on cygwin only):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function spinner_update() {
 case "${lastchar}" in
  "-") lastchar="\\";;
  "\\") lastchar="|";;
  "|") lastchar="/";;
  *) lastchar="-";;
 esac
 echo -ne "\b${lastchar}"
}

function spinner_start() {
  local msg="${@}"
  trap handle_sigint SIGINT

  if [ ! -z "${msg}" ]; then
   msg="- ${msg}: "
  fi
  lastchar="-"
  echo -n "${msg}${lastchar}"
}

function spinner_clear() {
  trap "" SIGINT
  msg="${@}"
  echo -e "\b${msg}"
}

function handle_sigint() {
  echo -e "\binterrupted."
  exit
}

lastrun="0"
spinner_start "Polling for changes (^c aborts)"
while true; do
 for ts in $(stat *.ts tsconfig.json package.json package-lock.json --format="%Y"); do
  if [ ${ts} -gt ${lastrun} ]; then
   lastrun="$(date +%s)"
   spinner_clear "changes detected."
   echo -n "- Changes detected, building: "
   tsc
   echo "done, running."
   node index.js test
   retstat="${?}"

   if [ ${retstat} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "*** Script returned error."
   else
    echo "- Script run successfully."
   fi
   spinner_start "Polling for changes (^c aborts)"
   break
  fi
 done

 if [ $(stat "${BASH_SOURCE}" --format="%Y") -gt ${lastrun} ]; then
  spinner_clear "watcher script changed."
  echo "*** Warning: This script has been changed. Aborting."
  exit 1
 fi
 sleep 1
 spinner_update
done
```

It will watch changes in the files in current directory via files' last changed time stamp; with a nice "spinner" updating whilst polling for changes; interrupts gracefully if `ctrl+c` is pressed, and will abort if the very same script is changed. Changes are needed to watch for changes in files within subdirectories.

Comment: I'm incredibly annoyed with typescript. This whole example worked last week when I written this. Now it simply doesn't and when I run the index.js file it can't resolve the String.test() during runtime. :(